# Nautilus not working on sudo

Tags: linux, gnome, sudo, root, nautilus

I've got Trisquel 7 GNU/Linux distro, with GNOME 3.8.4.

I'm finding impossible to create a folder in Nautilus, or drag and drop files into the Desktop, out of other options. I find this quite strange, as I'm used to work with only-root live USBs, and I still don't understand the user system n Linux. Whenever I try to perform any  action, Nautilus won't react; here I have some code I've tried...

**REGULAR ENTRY: $ NAUTILUS**

```
xvlaze@linux0:~$ nautilus

** (nautilus:4627): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

**SUDO NAUTILUS**

[Same message]

**SU**

```
root@linux0:/home/xvlaze# nautilus Unable to initialize DBus connection: Connection is closed (nautilus:4672): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_export: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed Error creating proxy: Connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18) Error creating proxy: Connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18) Error creating proxy: Connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18) Error creating proxy: Connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)

(nautilus:4672): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:154: Unable to connect to session bus: Connection is closed

(nautilus:4672): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:154: Unable to connect to session bus: Connection is closed

(nautilus:4672): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Connection is closed

(nautilus:4672): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Connection is closed No DBus connection available
```

I have never experienced something similar before, even when using other people's Linux computers. Does anybody have experienced something like this?

Comment: Try removing the `./local` folder, https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1190731#p1190731

Comment: @MariusMatutiae After that, `./local` reappears, and terminal returns me this message if I try to sudo nautilus: `xvlaze@linux0:~$ sudo nautilus
[sudo] password for xvlaze: 

(nautilus:1833): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
`

Comment: Pls read my Edit.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Worked following this commands:

    sudo apt-get purge nautilus
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nemo

[ENTER NEMO. Desktop will fix by itself. EXIT NEMO]

    sudo apt-get purge nemo
    sudo apt-get install nautilus
    sudo apt-get update

But now I can't access my Trash folder! When I want to open it, as root or not, it will return 'Operation not supported'. Strange thing...

Comment: UPDATE: This is crazy. After some time, my desktop icons disappeared again and I can't create any folder. What's more, `gksudo` nor `gksu` exist in my command line and xhosts doesn't seem to exist too. Finally, `gpasswd` won't recognize the dbus group. This is starting to be desperating.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem with your current installation of Nautilus, as if it had been corrupted somewhere during an upgrade or a re-install.

I would try re-installing Nautilus from scratch:

```
killall nautilus
apt-get purge nautilus 
apt-get update 
apt-get install nautilus
```

**EDIT**:

The problem is that root has neither an Xscreen session, nor a dbus connection. Different distros deal with this differently, for instance on my Kubuntu your command above works out of the box. The standard solution in these cases is to use `gksu` instead of `sudo`, because `gksudo` has been designed to address exactly these two problems.

Alternatively, you may enable root access to your screen (`xhosts +`) and add root to the dbus group,

```
 gpasswd -a root dbus
```

Should this not be enough, you will have to look into [polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Disable_suspend_and_hibernate) for Gnome, something however which I have never done, and on which I cannot offer any guidance.

Comment: That seems to be the solution, I will try it later. I don't understand what could produce this error. In order to add some info, I'll say that I firstly installed Trisquel from text, and then I instated Gnome via `sudo apt-get install gnome `. Thanks for your response, I'll let you know about the result asap.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. after following your indications, typing `sudo nautilus` will result in: `(nautilus:2736): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files`
`